# NVIDIA Visual profiler does not generate a timeline

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

My question is almost same as the question [asked here at SO before][1]. But no answer has been provided to it so, I am asking a separate question.

I am using CUDA 7.0 toolkit on a Windows-7 OS. I am using VS-2013.

I tried to generate the timeline of vector addition sample program and it worked. But when I follow exactly same steps to generate a timeline of my own code then, it keep showing a message "Running application to generate timeline". I know that the kernel gets called and everything is working.

`cudaDeviceReset()` call is also there after finishing everything related to CUDA.

**Program:** I have changed my original question to provide a minimal working example which can produce the same problem. The following code is not generating a timeline using `nvvp` *irrespective of the place where I put `cudaDeviceReset()`*.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

//OpenCV
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

__global__ void colorTransformation_kernel(int numChannels, int iw, int ih, unsigned char *ptr_source, unsigned char *ptr_dst)
{
    // Calculate our pixel's location
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    // Operate only if we are in the correct boundaries
    if (x >= 0 && x < iw && y >= 0 && y < ih)
    {   
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 0];
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 1];
        ptr_dst[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2] = ptr_source[numChannels*  (iw*y + x) + 2];
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    { 
        Mat image(400, 400, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        unsigned char *h_src = image.data;
        size_t numBytes = image.rows * image.cols * 3;
        int numChannels = 3;


        unsigned char *dev_src, *dev_dst, *h_dst;

        //Allocate memomry at device for SOURCE and DESTINATION and get their pointers
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src, numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst, numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char));

        ////Copy the source image to the device i.e. GPU
        cudaMemcpy(dev_src, h_src, numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        ////KERNEL
        dim3 numOfBlocks(3 * (image.cols / 20), 3 * (image.rows / 20)); //multiplied by 3 because we have 3 channel image now
        dim3 numOfThreadsPerBlocks(20, 20);
        colorTransformation_kernel << <numOfBlocks, numOfThreadsPerBlocks >> >(numChannels, image.cols, image.rows, dev_src, dev_dst);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        //Get the processed image 
        Mat org_dijSDK_img(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3);
        h_dst = org_dijSDK_img.data;
        cudaMemcpy(h_dst, dev_dst, numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        //DISPLAY PROCESSED IMAGE           
        imshow("Processed dijSDK image", org_dijSDK_img);
        waitKey(33);

    }

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

**Very Important Clue:** If I comment the line `while(1)` and hence run the code only once then, the `nvvp` generates timeline. But in my original project, I cannot get the timeline profile by doing so because, it contain multi-threading and other stuff due to which, there is no image to process during the first run. So, I must need some way to generate the timeline with a code containing infinite `while loop`.

Comment: Are you calling cudaDeviceReset or similarly explicitly closing the CUDA context?

Comment: I am calling `cudaDeviceReset()` after finishing all the tasks i.e. `kernel call`, `cudaMemcpyAsync(D2H)`, `cudaStreamSynchronize()` and `cudaFree()`.

Comment: @talonmies: I have provided a minimal working example. This project contains only one `kernel.cu` file. Basically, I have edited the same sample file which is generated by VS for a CUDA program. The sample file was generating the timeline though.

Comment: Isn't that an endless loop? How would expect the cudaDeviceReset() call will be reached in this code? Also you've been called out on this before, but if you are asking CUDA questions and providing CUDA repro cases, don't include OpenCV in it. It isn't necessary and it makes your repro case unrunnable by the people who mostly answer questions here

Comment: @talonmies: Actually, I thought that `cudaDeviceReset()` can be placed inside the while loop and then the whole process of memory initialisation, kernel call and GPU reset will be done during each run of while loop. But I was wrong and realised that I cannot get timeline profiling in an endless while loop (which I have mentioned in my update). I will post an answer tomorrow after conducting few more tests. I think that I can replace endless `while loop` with a `for loop` for limited number of run..that could be a possible solution for my case. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: At this point I have no idea what you are trying to ask, and I suspect you don't either. You have told us you know `cudaDeviceReset` must be called to finalise the profiling, and you have shown us code which you know doesn't emit profiling data because it doesn't call `cudaDeviceReset`. And you would like to know what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my code is the endless `while loop` due to which the `cudaDeviceReset()` were never being called. There are two possible solutions to deal with such situations:

1. If you are interested to have a look at timeline profiling only then, just comment your `while loop` and the `nvvp` would be able to reach the `cudaDeviceReset()` present at the end of `main()`.
2. There might be a situation where you must keep a loop inside your program. For example, in my original project containing multi-threading, there is no image to process during initial 180 run of `while loop`. To deal with such situations, replace your while loop with the `for loop` which can run for limited number of times. For example, the following code has helped me to get a timeline profiling of 4 number of runs. I am posting only the modified `main()`.

   ```
   int main()
   {
   cudaStream_t stream_one;
   cudaStream_t stream_two;
   cudaStream_t stream_three;

   //while (1)
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       cudaStreamCreate(&stream_one);
       cudaStreamCreate(&stream_two);
       cudaStreamCreate(&stream_three);

       Mat image = imread("DijSDK_test_image.jpg", 1);
       //Mat image(1080, 1920, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
       size_t numBytes = image.rows * image.cols * 3;
       int numChannels = 3;

       int iw = image.rows;
       int ih = image.cols;
       size_t totalMemSize = numBytes * sizeof(unsigned char);
       size_t oneThirdMemSize = totalMemSize / 3;

       unsigned char *dev_src_1, *dev_src_2, *dev_src_3, *dev_dst_1, *dev_dst_2, *dev_dst_3, *h_src, *h_dst;


       //Allocate memomry at device for SOURCE and DESTINATION and get their pointers
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_1, (totalMemSize) / 3);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_2, (totalMemSize) / 3);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_src_3, (totalMemSize) / 3);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_1, (totalMemSize) / 3);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_2, (totalMemSize) / 3);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dst_3, (totalMemSize) / 3);

       //Get the processed image 
       Mat org_dijSDK_img(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
       h_dst = org_dijSDK_img.data;
       //copy new data of image to the host pointer
       h_src = image.data;

       //Copy the source image to the device i.e. GPU
       cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_1, h_src, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_one);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_2, h_src + oneThirdMemSize, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_two);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_src_3, h_src + (2 * oneThirdMemSize), (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_three);

       //KERNEL--stream-1
       callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_1, dev_dst_1, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_one);
       //KERNEL--stream-2
       callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_2, dev_dst_2, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_two);
       //KERNEL--stream-3
       callMultiStreamingCudaKernel(dev_src_3, dev_dst_3, numChannels, iw, ih, &stream_three);


       //RESULT copy: GPU to CPU
       cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst, dev_dst_1, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_one);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst + oneThirdMemSize, dev_dst_2, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_two);
       cudaMemcpyAsync(h_dst + (2 * oneThirdMemSize), dev_dst_3, (totalMemSize) / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_three);

       // wait for results 
       cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_one);
       cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_two);
       cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_three);


       //Assign the processed data to the display image.
       org_dijSDK_img.data = h_dst;
       //DISPLAY PROCESSED IMAGE           
       imshow("Processed dijSDK image", org_dijSDK_img);
       waitKey(33);


   }

   cudaDeviceReset();
   return 0;
      }
   ```